# java rmi testing application

Tags: java, networking

i want to test a small app that has a centralized server and other chat clients are connectes to it... so far i tested it on my home network using "ipconfig" to find out the ip addresses of the machines. (192.168.x.x)
what if  i want to run the server on my dektop, and let a friend of mine connect through another network, what ip should he use to connect with me? i mean 192.168.x.x is not visible outside my home network right?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I assume your friends will use internet.

If you use RMI, then you have an RMIRegistry running on one of your machines.
Then what you must make this port available from outside. To achieve this, you must route the rmiregistry port (default is 1099) to the IP of the server. This is a consequence of NAT.

Comment: the rmi registry is running on the same machine as the server. and it is using 1099 port.

Answer (score 0):

As per alf's answer, you have to route port 1099 from your NAT dvice to your aerver host. This is done *at the NAT device.* You also have to route whatever port(s) you are exporting your remote objects on, which must therefore be fixed as well.